# Given a prime $\wp$, are there different primes $\wp_2$,..., $\wp_s$ such that $\wp \wp_2\cdots \wp_s$ is principal?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain, ramification

Let $A$ be a Dedekind domain. Let $\wp$ be a prime ideal in $A$. Can one find pair-wise different prime ideals $\wp_2$,..., $\wp_s$, also different from $\wp$, such that their product $\wp\wp_2 \cdots \wp_s$ is principal?

If not, is this true if we assume further that the ideal class group of $A$ is finite?

Many thanks and Merry Christmas!

Comment: by distinct you mean different, not that they are pair-wise disjoint correct?

Comment: @Mariah, yes I mean different, or more precisely pair-wise different.

Comment: Any DVR (e.g. $\mathbb Z_p$) would give a counterexample. But I suspect that any counterexample must be a DVR.

Comment: @Mathmo123 that's not true. Every DVR is a PID, thus we can take $s=0$, as $\wp$ itself is principal.

Comment: @MatheinBoulomenos ah - I assumed $s$ would have to be non-zero - the notation in the question implies that $s\ge 2$.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading notation, yes we can take $s=1$, in which case the product is empty and equal to $A$ by convention.